# Change Apple ID country without losing iCloud+ Family Sharing data

Tags: icloud, family-sharing

seeking some advice from anyone who has been through this scenario:

we are a family of 4 (2 adults, 2 children) with 2TB iCloud+ in Family Sharing.
We currently use about 600GB between us, each user over 5GB.

We are moving country, so need to change the Apple ID country.

What are the steps to do this without risk of losing the data?

Want to avoid downloading/uploading all the data (destination country is not so internet friendly with speed and caps).

Looking for a 'least fuss' solution with zero risk to the data.

Thanks, MJ.

Comment: Just wanted to lend advice: keep backups and tread carefully, the road ahead is not trivial